# Import data in to R from MongoDB in JSON Format

Tags: r, mongodb

I want to import data in JSON format from MongoDB in to R. I am using Mongolite package to connect MongoDB to R, but when i use mongo$find('{}') data is getting stored as dataframe. Please check my Rcode,

```
library(mongolite)
mongo <- mongolite::mongo(collection = "Attributes", db = "Test", url = 
                          "mongodb://IP:PORT",verbose = TRUE)

df1 <- mongo$find('{}')
```

df1 is getting stored as dataframe, but I want the data in JSON format only. Please give your suggestions for the same.

Edit -

Actual json structure converted in to list

[image]

But when i load data from MongoDB to R using mongolite package, data is getting stored as dataframe and then if i convert to list, the structure is getting changed and few extra columns are inserted in to list.

[image]

Please let me know on how to solve this issue.

Thanks
SJB

Comment: see [this issue](https://github.com/jeroen/mongolite/issues/109) on the mongolite github page. Also, you can use `jsonlite::toJSON( df1 )` on your result.

Comment: @SymbolixAU I have tried toJSON(df1) but it is converting df1 in to class Character but not as JSON

Comment: Can you give an example of `df1` (i.e., your output - just the `head()` will do, and then show why `jsonlite::toJSON( df1 )` doesn't give you what you want?

Comment: Hi @SymbolixAU... If i convert dataframe to list, this method populates few extra columns in the list. Thats why i am looking to load data directly as JSON from MongoDB  in to R. Is there any solution for the same. Thanks

Comment: Have you read the link in my first comment?